# Run sh file from php with cron

Tags: php, cron, debian, visudo

I have an sh file with file-removing commands.

I run it from php like this:

```
shell_exec("sudo -n ./truncatefiles.sh  2>&1");
```

Thats works fine if I open the PHP file from browser, but doesnt work from scheduled cron tab.

PHP user: `www-data`

If i run `whoiami` from cron, returns same: www-data

I added this to my visudo:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /www/sites/..../importscript/truncatefiles.sh
```

Shell exec for this sh file returns (from cron):

sudo: sorry, a password is required to run sudo

Why works it dirrefent way in cron?

What should I do for get it work?

Comment: it's an apache webserver, right?

Comment: yes, its 2.2.16 (Debian)

Answer (score 0):

PLease try to do the following,
Try to log your output from crotab to a file, 
* * myscript.php >> /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1
This way you can debug your script.
1. Also the check the user and permissions for your shell script, php file.
2. try with sudo crotab -e

Comment: I know the response: sudo: sorry, a password is required to run sudo

Comment: PHP file 777, sh file 777

Comment: shell exec this way: ./truncatefiles.sh  2>&1 ask password, beginning with sudo -n returns password is required. No more response :(

Comment: I would avoid having internet accessible PHP scripts having 777 permissions, it is a security problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding your shell script directly into your crontab and running it that way?